# Is it better to store configuration in a file or database?

Tags: php, mysql, file, configuration

I'm currently working on a project that uses MySQL for configuration, but now I'm starting to think it could slow down page loads.

So my question is, would it be better to store configuration options (that are read almost every page load) inside an XML/JSON file, or a MySQL database?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not **[YAML](http://yaml.org/)** =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to conside is how much config data there is, and perhaps how often it is likely to change. If the amount of data is small, then saving this in a database (if your not already using a db for anything else), would be overkill, equally maintaining a db for something that gets changed once every 6 months would probably be a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on your projects. If you want someone else to configure the application through the UI you can put the configurations into the database.

If its just you and some developers, and changes are not made frequently, put them in a file.